Proof of Jordan theorem for polygons
I am trying to prove the Jordan curve theorem for polygons without using topological notions, but only with the axioms of incidence and the axioms of order. In particular, I need to prove the following lemma:
"Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a simple closed polygon (a Jordan polygon) with $n\geq 4$ edges. Then, there exists a vertex $V$ such that $\mathcal{P}$ has a good triangle at V."
For "good triangle at $V$" I mean that the segment $V_-V_+$ ($V_-$ and $V_+$ are the vertices adjacent to $V$) does not meet $\mathcal{P}$ anywhere, except for $V_-$ and $V_+$. In the proof of this lemma, I assume Jordan theorem for polygons with $k<n$ edges. The proof I outlined is the following:
Let's assume, by contradiction, that there is no such vertex. Let $V^1$ be any vertex of $\mathcal{P} \Longrightarrow \mathcal{P}$ has not a good triangle at $V^1$, thus the triangle $V_-^1V^1V_+^1$ contains at least one vertex of $\mathcal{P}$; let $V^2$ be the closest to $V^1$. Then, the segment $V^1V^2$ does not contain points of $\mathcal{P}$. Again, $\mathcal{P}$ has not a good triangle at $V^2$ and we apply the same reasoning, finding a vertex $V^3$ such that $V^2V^3$ does not contain any point of $\mathcal{P}$....After a finite number of steps, since the polygon has a finite number of vertices, we must come back to $V^1$, so we have built a simple closed polygon $\mathcal{P}'$ such that $\mathcal{P}'$ meets $\mathcal{P}$ only at its vertices and $\mathcal{P}'$ has $k\leq n$ vertices.
Now, I have to prove that $k$ cannot coincide with $n$, so it must be $k<n$. This is the unique step of which I need to conclude the proof.
Do you have any ideas or suggestion on how to prove that $k<n$ ?
Thanks for any answer and help!

See for example the "Diagonal Lemma" here: https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/comptop/2023/notes/01-simple-polygons.pdf

But, that result uses the Jordan theorem in the definition of interior diagonal, right?

Is there any way to prove this result assuming Jordan theorem only for polygons with $k<n$ vertices, so via complete induction?

Maybe this is helpful: Two ears theorem

Your "good triangle" seems to be identical with an "ear" in the Two ears theorem. Furthermore, Max Dehn used the Two ears theorem for his proof of the Jordan curve theorem, too, which means that there is most likely no risk of circular reasoning.

Yes, a good triangle can be an ear or a mouth, but actually to talk about ears and mouths we need the notions of interior and exterior of a polygon....Do you know where can I find Dehn's proof of the Jordan theorem?

I do not know where to find it. Apparently, it is not easy to find: related question on mathoverflow

Let $\mathcal V^1$ be the set of all vertices of $\cal P$ inside the $V^1$ triangle. Let $V^2 \in \mathcal V^1$ and let $\mathcal V^2$ be all the vertices inside the triangle $V^1V^1_+V^2$. If $\mathcal V^2$ is not empty, choose $V^3$ from it and continue (always using $V^1$ and $V^1_+$ to form the triangles). As eliminated vertices at any step cannot be inside later triangles, this process must stop with an empty $\mathcal V^k$. Let $\mathcal P'$ be the triangle $V^1V^1_+V^k$. It has no internal vertices and as a triangle must be simple. (This does share an entire edge with $\cal P$.)

If having a shared edge between $\cal P$ and $\mathcal P'$ is an issue, then handle the case when $V^2$ is the only vertex inside the original triangle however you were planning to handle it in your version, and use a second internal vertex in the place of $V^1_+$. Also, include in $\mathcal V^k$ any vertices lying on the edges of the $k$-triangle other than the vertices that form it.
